# How to print the div whole content with horizontal scroll?

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have a div which has 20 columns and i want to print the whole data.

I have used window.print but its working only for visible part of window I used many methods and search in Google but could not find anything.

I want to print the whole data in one row

Can any one help for the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide an image or some markup

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a second CSS sheet for `@media print {}` and to change the width used so that it will wrap nicely when printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't print the scrolled part.

You need to use different  style-sheet for printing purpose, where there is no scroll applied.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css” href="sheet.css" media="print" />
```